# how retrieve longblob format

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

How i should display the longblob format?
I want to retreive "content" longblob format in MYSQL with c#.

```
    string MyConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=newsborad;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"; 

    //this is the connection with the MYSQL
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString); //communicate MYSQL
    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    conn.Open();
    //content is longblob format in MYSQL
    cmd.CommandText = "Select content from message where msg_id = @id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "1");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //how i should code?
    }
    conn.Close();
```

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526209/reading-blob-image-from-mysql-database has a good example

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql

Comment: hope this is more helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257941/retrieve-longblob-from-mysql-in-c-sharp