# How to convert an Image into BLOB (Binary Large Object) format

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need a comparison between an input image with the 
blob field in MySql table. so that i need to conver the image into BLOB format. 
i had tried a lot in previous days but faild to achieve a good,i here by summerise the result 
of my search for this comparison:

1. convert the image into byte array using the following code

   `Dim fileName As String
   ListBox1.Items.Clear()
   fileName = "D:\me.jpeg"
   Dim fs As New FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)' Create a byte array of file stream length 
   Dim ImageData As Byte() = New Byte(fs.Length - 1) {}'Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array

   fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length))'Close the File Stream

   fs.Close()
   For j As Integer = 0 To ImageData.Length - 1
   ListBox1.Items.Add(ImageData(j).ToString)' list out the byte array
   Next`
2. Retrive the blob field carasponds to the same field

   `ListBox1.Items.Clear() 
       mystring = "select image from blob_table where id='28' "
       openconnection() ' Methode to open a mysql connection
       cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(mystring, myconnection)
       imagebyte = cmd.ExecuteScalar
       For j As Integer = 0 To imagebyte.Length - 1
       ListBox2.Items.Add(imagebyte(j).ToString) ' list out the BOLB array
       Next
       closeconnection() ' Close the connection`
3. Both the list boxes are shown in the image below.

[image: Screen shot of the output]

Both the lists are entirely different, byte array is comparitevely very large than blob it having more than 10K values so the comparison become harder and does not give the expected result.

Is their any possibility to convert an image into blob format? through vb.net. or any other 
alternate solution for this comparison

Thanks in Advance for positive response....!

Comment: The data in the BLOB translates to `C:Usersvcidex92DesktopUntitled.png` - so it seems, that wehn storing the BLOB you stored the name of the file, not the file data. This means, that the BLOB is simply corrupt.

Comment: the path is mentioned as `D:\me.jpeg` not in c:

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading BLOB image from MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11526209/reading-blob-image-from-mysql-database)